# Use price variable and echo command in WP fuction correctly for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a function that could probably be written better but I'm having difficulty getting the price to display with the currency and decimals. I tried a few things like replacing `get_price` with `wc_price` and `get_price_html` and they didn't work.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code below and how to write those `echo` statements better so it outputs the following: `$x.xx per 1/2 yard`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'eut_single_tag_slug' );

function eut_single_tag_slug() {

    global $product;
    $price = $product->get_price();

    if ( has_term( 'half-yard', 'product_tag' ) ) {
        echo $price; 
        echo ' per 1/2 Yard';
    } elseif ( has_term( 'one-yard', 'product_tag' ) ) {
        echo $price; 
        echo ' per One Yard';
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, without any additional functions, you should get the price formatted as set in `WooCommerce > Settings > General > Currency options`.

Regarding your function, it should return the output, not echo it. In addition, the function itself provides you with `$price` and `$product` variables.

Furthermore, you always need to return a value (in case none of your conditionals matched), simply return the default value.

This your function rewritten, is tested and works:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'eut_single_tag_slug', 10, 2 );
function eut_single_tag_slug( $price, $product ) {
    if ( has_term( 'half-yard', 'product_tag' ) ) {
        return $price . ' per 1/2 Yard';
    }
    if ( has_term( 'one-yard', 'product_tag' ) ) {
        return $price . ' per One Yard';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Nice! That is much cleaner than what I was trying. 

I added this but it's not returning the text 'per One Yard' after the price even though the tag slug matches.  Is there any formatting issues in the above?

Comment: This works for me. Make sure you added "half-yard" or "one-yard" as one of your product tags. The change in price output should be visible on your shop page. Where are you checking the output?
I have also included the "add_action" part.

Comment: This works for me now as well.  the 10, 2 in the add_action was missing.

Thank you!